# How to solve fatal error after updating wordpress version?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

**Warning:** require(/home/vol4_4/epizy.com/epiz_265421##/htdocs/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-block-types-controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/vol4_4/epizy.com/epiz_265421##/htdocs/wp-settings.php** on line 256

**Fatal error:** require(): Failed opening required '/home/vol4_4/epizy.com/epiz_265421##/htdocs/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-block-types-controller.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in **/home/vol4_4/epizy.com/epiz_265421##/htdocs/wp-settings.php** on line 256

There has been a critical error on your website.

line 256 in wp-settings is:

```
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-block-types-controller.php';
```

Comment: Did the wordpress update completed successfully?

Comment: Hopefully you have a backup to fallback in case it doesnt work out